# Area 51 Discussions magic link shows wrong title

Tags: bug, chat, area-51, magic-links

When magic-linking to Area 51 Discussions using `[discuss.area51.se]` or `[area51.meta.se]`, the link shows up as:

> [Area 51](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/)

That should be fixed to say "Area 51 Discussions" instead, because the actual link is to the discussions site.

Proof: https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6640930#6640930 and https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6640932#6640932